# Unity3D(C#) - Как сделать всплыаающие окна?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно сделать всплывающие окна? Например, дойдя до конца уровня, игра должна остановится, и в центре должно всплыть окно, мол: " Вы завершили уровень '1' " и далее переход на другую сцену. Я искал в интернете информацию, но так и не получилось это реализовать. За ранее спасибо!

Comment: Может быть вам поможет это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423389/how-to-create-a-dialogue-box-and-display-it-when-an-object-in-clicked-in-unity-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать UI элементы, которые будут отключены в инспекторе по умолчанию. На кнопки можно [заранее добавить](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/script-Button.html) то, что будет исполняться при нажатии, а можно метод добавить [динамически](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html)

Как только игрок совершает все нужные действия, например, наступает на триггер, который стоит в конце уровня, эти элементы можно включать с помощью метода [SetActive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html), добавлять необходимые методы в EventHandler, если он пуст, и ждать действий игрока.